# Jquery redirect is not working from pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage which is supposed to redirect to another page after a user clicks on a button named "I Want It" with class ".et_bloom_submit_subscription". This button is part of a mailchimp form.

This button appears as part of a form on the sidebar, footer and on two different kinds of pop ups. The form also asks for name and email of the visitor.

This is the code that i used -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {

    function setup_onclick_redirect() {
        $('.et_bloom_submit_subscription').on("click", function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                if ($('.et_bloom h2.et_bloom_success_message.et_bloom_animate_message').css('display') == 'block') {

                    $(location).attr('href', 'http://startupstrong.com/webinar-on-building-brand-with-social-media/');
                }
            }, 4000);
        });
    }

    $(window).load(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            setup_onclick_redirect();
        }, 700);
    });

})(jQuery);
```

The above code successfully redirects a visitor after he gives his name and email on the form present in sidebar and footer.

**But it fails to redirect when user enter details on the pop up screen.**

It should work on the popup too, I am not sure what is happening :(

This is the link where problem appears - http://startupstrong.com/purple-cow-by-seth-godin-take-all-my-detailed-notes/

Note that, if you want to see the pop up multiple times just clear the cache and refresh the page. Then go to the end of the page, it should reappear. Please let me know if there is some problem.

Comment: And what is the point of this. why do you wait to add an event handler, and do you really just give the user 4 seconds to do something, then you redirect, ready or not? Also, use `window.location.href = url`

Comment: onclick event handler with timeout and without checking values fill or not is a total suck? Worthless.

Comment: The 700ms wait is required for my theme to load i think, it did not work without that. The 4000ms wait is for the email to be saved in mailchimp list, if it immediately redirects the email is not getting saved.

Its convoluted, by I don't know how else to do this. Do you have any idea?

Comment: If value is filled .et_bloom h2.et_bloom_success_message.et_bloom_animate_message will have display == 'block'. That why I am not checking the fields.

Comment: I have no idea, I can't even see this popup you're referring to ?

Comment: on the button click check values are fill or not, if yes then `window.location.href = "your url"`else remain their with some alert message

Comment: @Anant Major problem is that it is not working at all with the pop up. Why do you think that is happening?

For checking if its filled or not I am seeing if success message is displayed as block.

Comment: @adeneo Did you go to the bottom of the blog post? It should pop up when you reach the end.

Comment: the form submit should handle the redirect